# How do I take a photo like this?

Tags: lighting, photo-editing, effect

I really like the pictures taken by Kat Irlin, and I want to achieve the effect or the looks of the pictures she takes. Here is a sample below.

[image]

Comment: To save mattdm the trouble :-), please read [Important information for asking “What's this effect?” questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions) and update your question appropriately.

Comment: Get a woman in a black top to stand in front of a building and click...

Comment: In addition to articulating more clearly your goal... what have you tried? What kind of results to you get? Where do you think you're succeeding? What problems are you running into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kat Irlin uses Fujifilm gear and post-processes with VSCO "99% of the time" ([source](https://backofhouse.morganshotelgroup.com/creators/kat-irlin)).

But, I absolutely guarantee you that simply imitating what equipment and software she has will get you nowhere close to being able to "take a photo like this", or like Kat Irlin does in general. There are a bazillion Instagram users ([source](https://www.omnicoreagency.com/instagram-statistics/)), many using similar setups, and 99.999999% of them never make anything like this single photograph, let alone her [extensive porfolio](http://katirlin.com/).

On a reductionist side, you'll also need experience with lighting, a skilled or *very* patient model — and in many or most cases, an expert to do hair and makeup.

But that's not all of it. Natural talent will help significantly — or at least growing up with an eye for art. On top of that, add several years of full-time very hard work. *That's* what you need to take a photo like this.

To quote the photographer from [an interview](http://www.vanityfair.com/style/2016/10/kat-irlin-on-legendary-style):

> “Going into a shoot, I always have a vision in my mind. I make a conscious effort to not look at other photographers’ work because I don’t want to be inspired by anything that has already been done. I always want to have a unique and original concept.”

That seems worthy of imitation.